# Unable to change the list view using "All items" drop down list in SharePoint ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, custom-list

I have created the promoted links list in SharePoint 2013.I unable to change the view of the list by clicking the "All Items" drop down box in the SharePoint ribbon. After deactivating the "Metadata Navigation and Filtering" feature from 'Manage site features' , the drop down box is showing.I have used for SharePoint on-premise site .Suggest an idea to change the view without disabling the "Metadata Navigation and Filtering" feature.

Fig : Before deactivate "Metadata Navigation and Filtering" feature.

[image]

Fig : After deactivating the "Metadata Navigation and Filtering" feature.

[image]

Comment: Can you post some screenshots  ? Also, are you using OnPrem or Online ?